# Tools and utilities don't work when fish is made default shell

Tags: linux, fish

WSL2 running Ubuntu 20.04 | fish 3.3.1 (installed via PPA)

When I try to invoke tools like `poetry` and `rustup` (which were installed when I was using `bash`) in a temporary fish session (by running `fish` from my default bash shell), I get autocompletions and the tools work. But when I make `fish` my default shell (`chsh -s /usr/bin/fish`), I see `command not found` - these commands are not even picked from history! (Yes, I restarted my terminal after changing the default shell.) Could someone tell me how to rectify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from the last one - your command history in bash is stored in `.bash_history`. Like `.bashrc` and `.bash_aliases`, it's read by `bash`, not by `fish`. Most likely reason for commands and tools not being found in `fish` that your `$PATH` in `fish`-shell isn't the same as it is in `bash`.

Restore `bash` as your default shell, and read up about `fish` to learn how you can duplicate your `bash` environment in `fish`. When a temporary `fish`-shell works the way you want, you can make it the default shell.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I just checked the $PATH variables from the two shells; while they have many directories in common, the programs that were installed later are missing in `fish`.